# Need to always redirect to page.php?id=xxxx when an url contains &a=dl

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have many different incoming links from across the internet to my website like:
http://www.example.com/page.php?id=xxxx&highlight=xxxx%2xxxx&a=dl

or

http://www.example.com/page.php?id=xxxx&a=dl

or
any other kind or url you can think of. 
Only part which is always the same is that the referer url contains "&a=dl".

I want to redirect any such incoming url **which contains "&a=dl"** to just the specific "page.php?id=xxxxx" it also contains.

I have been reading different webpages about how to do this in htaccess but since there could be so many variables I am really lost on how to do this.

This rewrite stuff is already something I am pretty bad at but now it could contain any string I really dont get it anymore.

I hope someone can share his knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(id=[^&]+).*?&a=dl [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=302]
```